# Proving that if $L(\vec{v}_1),\ldots,L(\vec{v}_k)$ spans $W$ that $\dim(V) \geq \dim(W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Let $\vec{v}_1,\ldots,\vec{v}_k$ be vectors in a vector space $V$ and $L\colon V \rightarrow W$ be a linear mapping. How would you prove that if $L(\vec{v}_1),\ldots,L(\vec{v}_k)$ spans $W$ that $\dim(V) \geq \dim(W).$

Comment: What is $k$? Is $k=\dim(V)$? Are $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ linearly independent?

Comment: no, you're supposed to use the rank nullity theorem, and in the solutions it is claimed that Range(L)=W which I have no idea how that impliciation is made

Comment: Essentially this says that if $L$ is surjective then the dimension of the domain is at least as big as the dimension of the image.

Answer (score 2):

If $\dim V\lt\dim W$, then there aren't enough vectors to span $W$...

For $$\operatorname{rank}L+\operatorname{null} L=\dim V.$$

But $\operatorname{rank} L\ge\dim W$.

Comment: If you write \operatorname{rank}L instead of \text{rank}L then you automatically get proper spacing in things like $A\operatorname{rank}B$ and $A\operatorname{rank}(B),$ and I include both of those examples to show the context-dependent nature of the spacing: you see less space to the right of $\operatorname{rank}$ in the second example than in the first. $\qquad$

Comment: $\operatorname{rank}L=\dim W$.

Comment: @egreg it seems that in case the vectors $v_i$ are not independent we might not have equality...

Comment: @ChrisCuster So what? Can the rank of $L$ be greater than $\dim W$?

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I'll give hints on how to show $L$ is surjective (i.e. its range is $W$).

Suppose that $w \in W$. We need to show that $w$ is in the range of $L$.
Because $\{L(v_1), L(v_2), \ldots, L(v_k)\}$ spans $W$, we have

> $w = c_1L(v_1) + c_2L(v_2) + \cdots + c_kL(v_k)$ for some scalars $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k$.

Now use linearity to show that $w$ is in the image of $L$.

Comment: can you expand on this please?

Comment: What does it mean for $L$ to be linear? Use this with the expression in the spoiler to try and write $w = L(v)$ for some $v$.

Answer (score 0):

The map $L$ is surjective, so the rank-nullity theorem says
$$
\dim V=\dim\ker L+\dim\operatorname{range}L=\dim\ker f+\dim W
$$
Why is $L$ surjective? Because the span of $\{L(v_1),\dots,L(v_k)\}$ is contained in the image, for any set of vectors $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$. But, by assumption, the span of that particular set of vectors is $W$.